# Добавление элементов ниже других

Tags: c#, winforms

Использую WinForms. Мне необходимо добавлять динамически создаваемые панели в другую панель так, чтобы каждая новая находилась ниже ранее добавленной.
Как-то так, но динамически:

[image: картинка]

Comment: У каждого элемента есть координаты X и Y. Вот их вам нужно менять, что бы один элемент добавлялся ниже другого.

Comment: Как вариант, можете использовать `FlowLayoutPanel` или `TableLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Создать список для хранения дочерних панелей

```
List<Panel> childPanels = new List<Panel>();
```

2) Определить параметры расположения панелей

```
int panelDx = 5; // расстояние между панелями
int panelDy = 5; // расстояние от боковых границ родительской панели до дочерней
int panelHeight = 20;
```

3) Определить метод, который будет добавлять панель в родительскую `parentPanel`

```
    private void AddPanel()
    {
        int panelCount = childPanels.Count;
        childPanels.Add(new Panel()
        {
            Location = new Point(panelDx, panelDy + panelCount * (panelDy + panelHeight)),
            Size = new Size(parentPanel.Width - 2 * panelDx, panelHeight),
            BackColor = Color.Black,
        }
        );
        parentPanel.Controls.Add(childPanels[panelCount]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто получать позицию нижнего края последней панели (свойство `Bottom`) и прибавлять к ней нужный отступ. Например:

```
int y = offset;
if (parentPanel.Controls.Count > 0) 
    y += parentPanel.Controls[parentPanel.Controls.Count - 1].Bottom;
```

Это будет работать если панели всегда расположены в том порядке, в котором они были добавлены. Если положение панелей может меняться, то лучше завести отдельную переменную и сохранять в ней ссылку на ту панель, которая в данный момент является нижней.

Также можно вычислить нужную высоту по формуле

> y = отступ + индекс * (высота + отступ)

То есть как-то так:

```
int y = offset + (parentPanel.Controls.Count * (height + offset));
```

Но этот вариант, естественно, подойдёт только в том случае, если все дочерние панели будут иметь одинаковую высоту.

И, как ещё один вариант, можно просто перебирать все предыдущие панели, суммируя их высоту и отступы:

```
int y = offset;
foreach (Control c in parentPanel.Controls) y += c.Height + offset;
```

Этот вариант тоже может подойти, в некоторых случаях. Например, если `parentPanel.Controls` содержит не только панели, можно отфильтровать лишние контролы добавив в цикл условие `if (c is Panel)`.